# what does camera request code mean in Android

Tags: android, android-camera

could someone explain what the camera request code?

why do we use it?

i was trying a practice in android and i see the code.

this is my code that i do practice;

```
public class imageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button image;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resim);

        imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture);

        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: go through this for the answer - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Please add a bit more detail to your question. Are you asking what the value of CAMERA_REQUEST is used for?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make several calls in a single Activity to `startActivityForResult()` which allows different `Intent`s to do different actions. Use a request code to identify which is the `Intent` you are returning from.

**For example:**

You can start two activities for result:

```
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1889;
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
```

**and in your `onActivityForResult()`**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Do stuff with the camara data result
    }
    else if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Do stuff with the gallery data result
    }
}
```

Do note that the `private static final int`s are completely arbitrary.

Comment: thank you. i undestand your answer like others that answers in my question.

Comment: You're welcome! you can set one of them like a answer to avoid receiving more post. :D

Comment: I am calling the startAcitivityForResult from within a fragment and and my onActivityResult is inside the Activity. I am always getting random requestCode when I run the application. What should I do

Answer (score 3):

This is what it means:

When you start an activity for result, like request Camera to take your photo then return it to your calling activity, you pass it a unique integer value like `100001` or anything you have not used already in that class.

So, in short, `CAMERA_REQUEST` could be any value you define in your class like this:

```
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 10001;
```

Now, since you passed it when requesting a photo from the camera, you will use it to check the `requestCode` because it will have to match it if it is for the Camera itself.

I hope this helps you understand.

Answer (score 1):

Just to detect/confirm REQUEST when you Receive RESPONSE, we use CAMERA_REQUEST.

Answer (score 1):

it is used to receive camera intent result

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent

    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // User cancelled the image capture
    } else {
        // Image capture failed, advise user
    }
}
```

[See Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

Answer (score 1):

`onActivityResult()` can handle more then one reposes like if you launch intent to pick image from gallery its result is also received in `onActivityResult()`.

So to Detect which result we got we add a identifier thats why we use `CAMERA_REQUEST`. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about the reason for CAMERA_REQUEST then you can think of it as an arbitrary tracking value you provide and that will be passed back to you when the results are returned from the call to startActivityForResult.

The documentation says this,

```
requestCode int: If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits.
```

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)